# Index 11 from Calendar prints months in string as "January"

Tags: java, calendar, utc

While converting `jan 01 2017 00:00:00 NPT to utc`, the result is 11(month index in Calendar) 31 2016 18:15:00 which is okay. But if i extract the month as string from index 11, it gives me January which must be December.
Actual code

```
Date date = new Date(1483208100000L);
System.out.println("date: " + date);

System.out.println("\nUTC with month as index::::");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.setTime(date);

System.out.println("Year: " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ", month: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + ", day: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("hours: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ", minutes: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ", seconds: " + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));


System.out.println("\nUTC with month as String::::");     
String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(calendar.getTime());       
System.out.println("Year: " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ", month: " + month + ", day: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("hours: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ", minutes: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ", seconds: " + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Output of code

```
date: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 NPT 2017

UTC with month as index::::
Year: 2016, month: 11, day: 31
hours: 18, minutes: 15, seconds: 0

UTC with month as String::::
Year: 2016, month: January, day: 31
hours: 18, minutes: 15, seconds: 0
```

Comment: Your output is not reproducible, but the output is in my test like the one described by @gzp__ So all is fine. I strongly suspect that you are just confused about the behaviour of method `java.util.Date.toString()` which uses a different timezone than UTC and hence can produce even another month (January in NPT, December at UTC). And if you don't set the zone on `SimpleDateFormat` then the formatter will use your system zone NPT, not UTC.

Comment: calendar.getTime() returns a date and also convert time to local . I tested in eclipse. so i extracted month name by index from calendar. :)

Comment: I hope you try run above code and see output

Comment: Yes, I have already run your code even before writing my first comment. Cannot reproduce for me. But I have also given the hint that you should set the zone on your formatter to UTC in order to avoid "January" in last but one line of your output example.

Comment: oh yes, i tried setting timezone on SimpleDateFormat  and got desired output.         i also fixed it with just after asking question by :: String monthName = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)];    Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

your code output this:

```
date: Sat Dec 31 18:15:00 GMT 2016

UTC with month as index::::
Year: 2016, month: 11, day: 31
hours: 18, minutes: 15, seconds: 0

UTC with month as String::::
Year: 2016, month: December, day: 31
hours: 18, minutes: 15, seconds: 0
```

which looks correct to me

Comment: String month = new  SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(calendar.getTime());     //This line "calendar.getTime())" converts back UTC time to local time which has month "0" index which is January. So it was returning January . fixed it. So, i extracted month from index which is as :::         String monthName = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)];

Comment: I just copied the output from console after running code which is returning January. :)